# Decoding RAW protobuf data in Charles Proxy

Tags: android, proxy, protocol-buffers, decode

I have captured some traffic between an Android application and a website using Charles Proxy. Charles identifies the traffic as a Protocol Buffer stream.

The structure as shown in Charles:

```
- site.com
|
-- sub
|
--- message.proto
```

The raw message:

```
POST site.com/sub/message.proto HTTP/1.1
token: random
Id: random
Authorization: Basic OTI[..]
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; Galaxy Nexus Build/JWR66Y)
Host: site.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 580

��hï õÜÕñ6iaõ*|{6¤oQIùk*Õ¤Å¾¼   
S_½ª¥8.3ÝÎu öÚ´êVFBeùõÈî¿;µ¼ö%S [...]
```

I have tried a few things to decode the content, but in vain. The command `proton decode_raw < message.txt` results in a fail message `Failed to parse input`. Now I am not sure if the message is really a protobuf message since the Content-Type in the headers does not indicate that protobuf is used. I have also saved the traffic as a `.bin` file.

Charles has the capability to display the contexts of the protobuf message, but requires the corresponding descriptor file. To get the descriptor file I however need the actual `.proto` file which I do not have.

So, am I forced to decode the message by hand or are there other possibilities which I overlooked?

I suspect that application-level encryption is used and Charles identifies the traffic as protobuf unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the content is simply compressed:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Try decompressing it with gunzip.

I agree that it is likely *not* a protobuf. Charles Proxy is probably confused by the URL ending in `.proto`.

Note that when attempting to decode the data (whether as a protobuf or as gzip), you'll need to make sure you are only decoding the *body* of the request, i.e. not the textual HTTP headers. Note that editing the headers out in a text editor likely will *not* work, since converting binary data to text usually corrupts it. You can probably best extract the data by doing:

```
tail -c 580 message.txt | zcat
```

or, if you think it could be a protobuf after all:

```
tail -c 580 message.txt | protoc --decode_raw
```

Note that 580 comes from the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: I completely overlooked the `gzip` encoding. Thank you. I will first look into that.

Comment: @Safaci Oops, actually now that I look at it, I configured `Accept-Encoding` for `Content-Encoding`. `Accept-Encoding` does not specify the request encoding, it specifies what the client will accept in response. So I think I was wrong. But the content clearly isn't form data, so the `Content-Type` is clearly wrong too. Trying to gunzip is not a bad idea anyway.

Comment: To add some extra information, the response to message.proto is configure as `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8. The content is also unreadable: `�E�/I�R����#�?�<&LBZYy����0�t��6`.